# Why are my fluid simulation reflections so low res?

Tags: fluid-simulation, reflection

I have been getting my feet wet on fluid sims this week, even bought the Flip Fluids addon, but no matter what I do, how much resolution I give the fluid, how many subdivisions I give the obstacle, my reflections keep coming out in square blocky shapes.

I have this round light reflecting from the sphere that I filled with water but the reflection looks like I made it on Minecraft instead.

This render has a sim resolution of only 65, but I've tried all the way to 350 and the reflections looked the same. The World Scale is 2.07m.

Shading Smooth won't do anything either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the object shading to smooth?

Comment: Yes, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Would you please give more information or even better, upload the file at https://blend-exchange.com  and follow the instructions there to edit the link into your question? As it stands, it is hard to answer. A fluid sim has a lot more settings than just the resolution divisions, also I do not see the material you used for the water, I have no idea what lights/background there is to be reflected; it is not even exactly clear from your question if this is a _Mantaflow_ simulation or if you used the mentioned _Flip Fluids_ for it...

Comment: I apologize, you made a good point. I have uploaded the file, if you have any insights I would appreciate it.